# Fetching all the database records where column value is between a start date and the current date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a start date and an end date column in the database. I want to fetch all records where current date is between the start date column and the end date column values using php and MySQL.

How can i get the records between those dates?

The code which I have written is

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT *
  FROM test2 
 WHERE
CURDATE() BETWEEN startdt AND enddt
");
```

and the result which I'm getting is :
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i6zj.png)

As in the result above, I want to return all the records where the current date lies between the start date column value and the end date column value.

Comment: With `between` clause of course!

Comment: yes , thank you , but I have tried between clause it is working fine but I'm not getting complete record from start to end .

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE
 CURDATE() BETWEEN startdt AND enddt");

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant code, expected result, the result you're actually getting and some example data from your database.

Comment: this is my query where I get the current date record but I want to get the next or previous day records when the user enters to database along with current date record.

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE
 CURDATE() BETWEEN startdt AND enddt");                              This is my query where i'm getting current record of current date or start date . including with that I wanted to get all the records which starts with start date and till end date.

Comment: We saw it the first time. Please _edit your question_ to include all relevant code and a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Yes. No pictures thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT *
  FROM test2 
 WHERE
startdt <= CURDATE() AND enddt >= CURDATE()
");
```

Comment: `Between startdt and enddt` is a better option and already implemented by the OP, if that is not working, this will not work too.

Comment: I'm interesting in knowing what is 'better' about it for small data sets? Also, how do we know this won't work? It's a simpler to read and modify query which may well be the solution for OP and anybody else who finds this question.

Comment: *I'm interesting in knowing what is 'better' about it for small data sets?* - readability. *Also, how do we know this won't work?* - Because both are exactly same. *It's a simpler to read and modify query* - You just fixed a typo you made writing it.

Comment: I don't agree about readability. How does a beginner know whether BETWEEN include or exclude a exact match on date for example. `>=` isn't able to be confused. It is simpler to modify. I just did it. It was clear where my error was.